# Conditional binding in column of datagrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a `DataGrid` which itemsSource is an `ObservableCollection<MyType>`. This type has this properties:

```
long ID;
long IDCategory;
long? IDState01;
long? IDEstate02;
long? IDEste03;
```

I have 3 categories, if it is category 1, IDState01 is not null and the others states are null. If category is 2, the IDState02 is not null and the others are null and son on.

I have a state column in my `DataGrid`, which value depends on the category. So I would like to binding to the correct property depending on the category, so if the category is 1, it would bind property state01, if the category is 3 it would bind property state02 and so on.

I think that my `DataGrid` would be something like that:

```
<DataGrid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,5,5,5" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="State">
            <!--Something here, perhaps a datatrigger.-->
        </DateGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Thanks.

EDIT: I would like to do it in XAML if it is possible, instead of using a converter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to do it in XAML if it is possible ...

You could use a `DataGridTemplateColumn`:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="State">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IDCategory}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding IDState01}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IDCategory}" Value="2">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding IDEstate02}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IDCategory}" Value="3">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding IDEste03}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBox>
                <TextBox.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IDCategory}" Value="1">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding IDState01}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IDCategory}" Value="2">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding IDEstate02}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IDCategory}" Value="3">
                                <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding IDEste03}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBox.Style>
            </TextBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 2):

introduce a property which will get/set the correct state based on category:

```
public long? State
{
    get 
    { 
        if (IDCategory == 1) return IDState01; 
        if (IDCategory == 2) return IDState02; 
        return null;
    }
    set 
    { 
        if (IDCategory == 1) IDState01 = value; 
        else if (IDCategory == 2) IDState02 = value; 
    }
}
```

in DataGird bind column to a new property:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="State" Binding="{Binding State}"/>
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to introduce a new property, because it is a POCO entity that it is used various layers. I would like  to avoid to introduce a property only for the view.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía, views work with view models - because view models can and should have data in the format convenient for views

Answer (score -1):

I think you will need own DataTemplate for each category and DataTemplateSelector to assign DataTemplates based on category type.